# type conversion regarding null & undefined

Tags: javascript

As we all know null & undefined are falsy values.
But why does the first snippet of code work and the second does not?

```
// #1
if (!undefined) {   // or (!null)
  console.log("hi"); // => hi
}
enter code here

// #2
if (undefined == false) {  // or (null == false)
  console.log("hi"); => never gets executed
}
```

Is there a specific reason for this or is it just a language specification?
Other falsy values such as 0, "", false (except NaN) work and I guess they are being converted to false.

Comment: Because `undefined` *is not* `false` ?

Answer (score 2):

Because being "falsey" is not the same as being *equal* to `false`, which is why that term needed to be invented.

Comment: Yes, but 0 is also a falsey value, but 0 == false => true. This works for the other falsey values as well (except NaN). But why do null & undefined behave this way?

Comment: @arthur because `true / false` is analogous to `1 / 0` in CS while `undefined` and `null` mean "doesnt exist"

Comment: So if ("" == false) => true because they are being converted to analogous numbers. But undefined & null cannot be converted to numbers. Is that correct to say?

Comment: @arthur yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` only equals `null`, but not `false` by definition:

```
 undefined == null // true
 undefined == false // false
```

And yes thats not really for a specific reason, just to confuse people:

```
 [] == false // true
```

So all you can learn from thisis, is that you should always use `===`

Comment: I want to clarify one thing, so some falsy values such as undefined & null when being compared are not really converted to false or true? In the book "JS and jQuery" there is a line that says 
   if (document.getElementById("header") == true) the left side returns an object which is truthy but it is not equal to a Boolean value of true. This is what confused me.

Comment: @arthur If you compare a primitive to an object, the object will be converted into a primitive. Therefore `obj == true` will only work if `valueOf` / `toString` of `obj` return `1` or `"1"` or `true`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **undefined** and **null** are two different primitive values.

**undefined** means that the variable is created but not been assigned any **value**
and so it acts as a **falsy** value, while **null** represents a non-existing reference and so it's **falsy** too,
Now in your case,

```
if(undefined==false){
     //the code in here will never be executed
}
```

->As **undefined** has no value while **false** does.so,

```
undefined==false
//is false as false(with a value) can't be 
//equal to undefined which has no value
```